# vim remap <C-W>d not working as expected

Tags: vim

I would like to remap `<C-W>d` (from cucumber-vim) to a simple mouse double-click. I tried 
`noremap <2-LeftMouse> <C-W>d`
 
but that doesn't do anything except give me `E388: Couldn't find definition`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `noremap` disallows mappings of rhs. See `:help :noremap`:

> :no[remap]  {lhs} {rhs}
>
> Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes where the map command applies. Disallow mapping of {rhs}, to avoid nested and recursive mappings. Often used to redefine a command.

You defined your mapping using `noremap`, so you can't use the feature of cucumber-vim. Instead it uses default `<C-W>d` behavior, `:help CTRL-W_D`:

> Open a new window, with the cursor on the first macro definition line that contains the keyword under the cursor.  The search starts from the beginning of the file. If a count is given, the count'th matching line is jumped to.

Actually this raises `E388: Couldn't find definition` error.

So, if you want cucumber-vim behavior, try `map <2-LeftMouse> <C-W>d`. For your information, the following is the definition of `<C-W>d` in cucumber-vim.

```
nnoremap <silent> <script> <buffer> <C-W>d :<C-U>exe <SID>jump('split',v:count)<SID>foldopen<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Yous... I'm going to update my .vimrc tomorrow and test it out!